# JMeter - dynamic ramp up according to threads number

Tags: jmeter

I want to execute JMeter with thread number in property, that can be 10-1000 and set the optimal ramp up period.

In [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) it's suggested to start with number of threads:

> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.

But in my servers it's not working well in this configuration and I need more than double the thread number.

Can I set the ramp up using a formula as thread Number (property value) * 2.5? or maybe should I add a Timer a the start of each thread for this purpose?

Currently if I put `2*2.5` in Ramp-Up period it consider it as 0

> INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=2 ramp-up=0 perThread=0.0 delayedStart=false

I prefer solution in JMeter vanilla without plugins.

Comment: You can't use calculations in this field

Comment: @ShaiAlon see accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [__groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function to use property value:

```
${__groovy(2.5*props.get("rampup").toInteger()),)}
```

> The __groovy function evaluates Apache Groovy scripts passed to it, and returns the result.
>
> **props** - JMeterProperties (class java.util.Properties) object

Comment: I want to run 1st thread with 15 ramp up period but after that at 4 ramp up time. Is there any way to do this from jmeter.

Comment: This is not true - you should get the number of threads, not the rampup value itself - according to the title "dynamic ramp up according to threads number"