# Jmeter test plan run requests not consistently

Tags: jmeter

I have such test plan:

[image]

The issue here is that requests not consistently. It should run **win** request for each **bid** request if **bid** response code is 200 but in my case, it running all **bid** requests and only after start running **win** requests

Description:

- **bid requests** - is CSV Data set config wit random jsons for each bid request (did like mentioned [here](https://www.testingexcellence.com/jmeter-tutorial-how-to-send-a-json-file-as-request-in-body/))
- **thread** - it's a thread with 200 users and 1 loop
- **bid** - post request, for body I'm using one of json files `${__FileToString(/home/user/Downloads/jmeter/jsons/${__eval(${JSON_FILE})}.txt,,)}`.
  Also **bid** request include currency, bidid etc. it's Json
  extractors, I'm using that data to generate correct **win** URL for
  each **bid**.
- **if bid made** - if controller run **win** request only if **bid** response code is 200
- **win** -  get request, where URL queries are different depends on **bid** response (using Json extractors). Url looks like: 
  `win?auctionId=${AUCTIONID}&bidId=${BIDID}&impId=${IMPRESSIONID}&seatId=${SEAT}&price=${__javaScript((Math.random()* (4 - 1)+1).toFixed(4);)}&cur=${CUR}&adId=${ADID}`

  I would be grateful for any help!!!

Comment: what's your ramp up period in thread group?

Comment: ramp up is 1 second

Comment: Actually looks like each  win request using correct URL depends on related bid, but still I need to run win right after related bid not after all bid requests

Comment: your issue happens to me only when I choose 0 ramp up, can you try with 5 seconds ramp up?

Comment: yeah with 5 seconds it works, but what was the issue,  response time to slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With low ramp up period first requests will be sent in parallel on multi threads test.

If you read [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)

You should increase the "ramp-up" until it equals to the number of threads.

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running.

You can check related [dynamic ramp up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616337/jmeter-dynamic-ramp-up-according-to-threads-number)